# Multiple Controllers vs one large controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rather large database in rails. Currently I am in the process of creating my controllers.  Since the tables are relational to each other would it be better to have one large controller or with an associated view or several controllers (one for each table) with a few view to access all of the necessary information and display that information?

Answer (score 5):

It is generally better to have more controllers as it is much easier to keep to the restful paradigm.  It's not unusual to have several controllers for the same model even.  So in the end many small controllers with little to no logic is better than monolithic